# Stream a large file from URL straight into a gzip file

Tags: python, stream, python-requests, compression, gzip

I want to stream a large file into a gzip file directly, instead of downloading it all into memory and then compressing. This is how far I have gotten (does not work). I know how to just download a file in python and save and I know how to compress one, it is the streaming part that does not work.

Note: this linked csv is not large, it is just an example url.

```
    import requests
    import zlib

    url = f"http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv"

    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        compressor = zlib.compressobj()
        with open(save_file_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(compressor.compress(r.raw))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I figured it out:

```
with requests.get(url, stream=True, verify=False) as r:
    if save_file_path.endswith('gz'):
        compressor = zlib.compressobj(9, zlib.DEFLATED, zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16)
        with open(save_file_path, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*1024):
                f.write(compressor.compress(chunk))
            f.write(compressor.flush())
    else:
        with open(save_file_path, 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```